# How to load components in a right way in angular 7

Tags: html, css, angular, angular7

My app structure like this

```
 <app-header>
 <router-outlet>
 <app-footer>
```

But here the problem is when I go to some page since angular loads footer component first before loading the router outlet 
My router outlet is coming over the footer component which hides the footer

What am I doing wrong here ?
How to load all the components perfectly without occuring any html , css issues

Comment: If you open the app in a browser and inspect the footer in Developer Tools, are you able to manipulate the layout to look the way you'd like it to look?

Comment: create demo on stackblitz.com. this seems to be css issue and you should put more code for better understanding

Comment: Sure thanks , I will improve the content

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I am having the same problem in Angular 9 with Flex-layout

Comment: No actually to solve it I had to use window.location.href so it loads the page then it renders correctly but this is not the right way I couldn't find solution